# Almacenar y evaluar entero introducido por teclado en JAVA

Tags: java, variables, while, int

estoy empezando a programar en Java y estoy realizando un ejercicio en el que se debe adivinar un número generado aleatoriamente. El código completo que tengo es este: `public class AdivinaNumero {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numInt, numMax, numOculto, seleccion, numUsuario;
    int contadorIntentos = 0;

    System.out.println("Adivina el número oculto.");
    System.out.println("\nMENÚ");
    System.out.println("\t1) Configurar.");
    System.out.println("\t2) Jugar.");
    System.out.println("\t3) Salir.");

    System.out.print("\n\tIntroduzca su elección: ");

    do {

        seleccion = teclado.nextInt();
                    
        if ((seleccion != 1 || seleccion != 2 || seleccion != 3)){
            System.out.print("\n1Introduzca una selección válida: ");
        }
        
    } while (seleccion != 1 || seleccion != 2 || seleccion != 3);
    

    if (seleccion != 3) {
        if (seleccion == 1) {
            System.out.println("\nConfigure el número máximo de intentos permitidos: ");
            numInt = teclado.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Confiugre el valor máximo del número aleatorio: ");
            numMax = teclado.nextInt();
        } else {
            numInt = 5;
            numMax = 10;

            System.out.println("\nJugando con los valores por defecto. Número máximo = 10. Número de intentos = 5.");
        }

        numOculto = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * numMax + 1);
        
        do{
            System.out.print("\nIntroduzca su número: ");
            numUsuario = teclado.nextInt();
            
            contadorIntentos++;
            
            if (numUsuario == numOculto){
                System.out.println("Enhorabuena, el número oculto era: " + numOculto);
                System.out.println("Ha necesitado " + numInt + " intentos.");
            } else{
                System.out.println("El número oculto no es el " + numUsuario + ". Siga probando.");
                System.out.println("Intentos restantes: " + (numInt - contadorIntentos));
            }
        }while (contadorIntentos < numInt && numUsuario != numOculto);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Programa finalizado.");
    }

}
```

}`

El programa compila pero a la hora de ejecutarlo e introducir un número del 1 al 3 me muestra que el número introducido no es uno de esos tres valores así que no me sale del primer bucle while pero no encuentro dónde está el error ya que si imprimo la variable selección sí que me muestra el valor entero que he introducido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en la condición del while y del if `seleccion != 1 || seleccion != 2 || seleccion != 3`, esta será true siempre, pues estás comprobando si seleccion es distinto de 1 de 2 o de 3, por lo que si por ejemplo seleecion = 1, se evaluará como  `false || true || true` que al usar or, es true.

Lo que tu querías hacer es `seleccion != 1 && seleccion != 2 && seleccion != 3`, pues quieres comprobar si seleccion es distinto de 1 de 2 y de 3.